# Add dependency to the CMake-generated build-system itself

Tags: cmake

**In short:** I know how to add dependencies to targets, in a CMake-generated build system. But I would like to add dependencies to the generated build-system itself.

**Longer question:** In the CMake-generated build process of [cgal](/questions/tagged/cgal), we would like CMake to automatically re-run the configuration step, when certain files are modified. Unneeded details are hidden below:

> As a matter of fact, we generate using CMake the build system for the CGAL libraries/examples/demos, but also at the same time the build system for our Doxygen-generated documentation. The `Doxyfile` is generated from multiple files.

When the CMake generator is "`Makefile`", there is a special target in the `Makefile`, that is named `rebuild_cache`, but that target (at the Makefile level) is not a CMake-target. And anyway, I look for a solution that is cross-platform, that is: usable with all CMake generators. I have the impression that what I want is not yet doable with CMake. Can you please confirm, so that I can fill a documented feature-request?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since CMake 3.0, you can add such a file to the directory property [`CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS.html). This property holds a list of files; if any of them changes, CMake will trigger re-configuration.

Here is a small example. Assuming your `Doxyfile` is generated from `Doxyfile.in.1` and `Doxyfile.in.2` in the current source directory, the property could be used like this:

```
set_property(
  DIRECTORY 
  APPEND 
  PROPERTY CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS 
  Doxyfile.in.1
  Doxyfile.in.2
)
```

---

If you're using CMake 2.x, the property `CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS` is not available, but you can use the following trick:

Pass the files through `configure_file()`, even if you just `COPYONLY` them someplace and don't use the resulting copies. `configure_file()` introduces precisely the buildsystem dependency you're looking for.

This works, but it adds the overhead of copying the file.

<sub>(Note: This trick was also the original content of this answer, since I was not aware of `CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS` at time of answering).</sub>