# Code generator generating its own CMake files and targets

Tags: cmake, code-generation

Let's assume I have a script that generates a set of source files forming a target I want to link against in a `CMakeLists.txt`. If the file names are known to the latter then the usual `add_custom_target()` and `add_custom_command()` commands will make it possible to use the generated files as target sources.

Let's assume, though, that only the generator script knows the file names and locations. How can a target library be generated so that the parent `CMakeLists.txt` can link against it without its knowing the actual file names?

Note that the dependency topic isn't in this question's scope as the script knows itself when to regenerate or not. It's not the finest use of CMake, but it's sufficient in this use case.

**Idea #1**

The script also generates a `generated.cmake` file included by the parent one using `include(generated.cmake)`. Problem: CMake doesn't find `generated.cmake` as it isn't existing at configuration time.

**Idea #2**

Similar to idea #1, but the script is called with the `execute_process()` so that `generated.cmake` is present at configuration time. Problem: The script is not called anymore at subsequent builds, thus ignoring possible changes to its input.

**Idea #3**

The script passes back a list of targets and files that is *somehow* considered by the parent `CMakeLists.txt`. So far I couldn't find a way to do so.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25482963/1945549 shows a way to retrigger the configuration step, i.e. the `execute_process()` command when a specific file changes. It gets me closer to what I'm aiming at, but I face the problem that I don't know all relevant input files (as the script parses the input files itself to derive other input files).

Comment: "Problem: The script is not called anymore at subsequent builds, thus ignoring possible changes to its input.". The problem is clearly about the dependency tracking, which **contradicts** to "Note that the dependency topic isn't in this question's scope". So whether dependency tracking is relevant or not?

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Thanks for pointing this contradiction out. I'm working currently on a solution that actually calls the script using `execute_process()` and has the script "publish" its identified input files so that the parent CMake file can add them to the directory's `CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS` property. I'll describe it thoroughly as possible answer as soon as it is finalized.

Comment: Command `add_executable` requires all source files to be specified at *configuration step*. As you don't know source file, generated by your script, you have no other way than call that script at configuration stage, and collect the generated files using, e.g. `file(GLOB)`. So your "Idea #1" and "Idea #2" are just inevitable. This is described in that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076307/cmake-globbing-generated-files. And dependency tracking for the generating script is just **another** problem, which is described by the question referenced by you.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I kind of used your suggestion but eventually replacing file(GLOB) by a CMake file generated by the script itself (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came with is eventually a mixture of all three ideas.

## Solution to idea #1's problem

`execute_process()` actually ensures that `generated_targets.cmake` is present at configure time.

## Solution to idea #2's and #3's problems

As stated in [this answer to "Add dependency to the CMake-generated build-system itself"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25482963/1945549), the `CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS` directory property can be edited to add files whose touching re-triggers the configure step.

The key success factor is that this property can be set after the initial `execute_process()` call so that the script can identify and list its input dependencies (in an output file) that are then added to `CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS`, hence also solving the input dependency problem.

## Resulting pseudo code

```
# The script generates:
# - <output_dir>/cmake/input_files
# - <output_dir>/cmake/generated_targets.cmake
execute_process(
  COMMAND myScript
    --output-dir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated
)

# Mark the input files as configure step dependencies so that the execute_process
# commands are retriggered on input file change.
file(STRINGS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated/cmake/input_files _input_files)

set_property(
  DIRECTORY APPEND PROPERTY CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
    ${_input_files}
)

# Add the generated CMake targets.
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/generated/cmake/generated_targets.cmake)
```